# transform return key pressed in "tab key" in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, tabs, return

I found an example for creating an angular directive to "wrap" return key and send tab instead..
Here the example... 
http://plnkr.co/edit/nLEXB7iCePWNCIcodyFu?p=info
but it doesn't work: how I can find the next input box in my form? and how I can't send it the focus?

Answer (score 1):

this works fine in my case:
*$("input:input")[$("input:input").index(document.activeElement) + 1].focus();*

I think it's better (for performance) to use the "compile property" in directive instead of "link" (removing scope parameter)